# Cannot test build Android application on my HTC Evo

Tags: java, android

I cannot test build Android application on my HTC Evo at all. I searched online for answers, but nothing helped, including updating all the software.

The Eclipse launched Emulator doesn't recognize it as an external device either.

Any ideas? I have a presentation at my job tomorrow, and it has to be on the phone.

Comment: you are trying to install the app on your phone? are you using linux? windows?mac?

Comment: Try typing "adb devices" from the command-line and see if your device shows up.

Comment: ... and did you turn on debugging on your device? And if you are using Windows, I think you need to install the right USB drivers. More info: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: Note that the HTC device driver should be available from the HTC Web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above you need to download Drivers separately. You can download HTC Hero drivers from here

Just unzip and refer this path so that eclipse could recognize your device

http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Drivers/HTC-Hero-Drivers-81097.shtml